# Yii - form with CMultiFileUpload won't submit files

Tags: file, upload, yii, submit

I need some help with a little strange problem.
My problem is that submit button does not submit files to controller when using CMultiFileUpload.

I have this very simple view to upload multiple files:

```
<?php 
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            ));?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sourceCode'); ?>   
    <?php
        $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'name' => 'sourceCode',
            'attribute'=> 'sourceCode',
            'max'=>5,
            'accept' =>'zip',
            'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', 
            'denied' => 'Invalid file type',));  
     echo $form->error($model,'sourceCode');?>  
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Here is my model:

```
class UploadSolutionForm extends CFormModel
{

public $sourceCode;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('sourceCode', 'file', 'types'=>'zip', 'allowEmpty'=>false, 'wrongType'=>'Only .zip files allowed'),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
            'sourceCode' => 'Uploaded file',
    );
}
}
```

And here is probably the simplest action ever:

```
public function actionUpload()
{

    $model = new UploadSolutionForm();

    if(isset($_POST['UploadSolutionForm']))
    {
        echo 'Got it!';
    }

    $this->render('solve',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

But when I click on submit it does not echo anything, but it does with this code (CMultiFileUpload is replaced with fileField):

```
<?php 
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            ));?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'sourceCode');?>
    <br><?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'sourceCode');?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'sourceCode');?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
<?php 
$this->endWidget();?>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Anyone? As I see it form with CMultiFileUpload doesn't POST to controller. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works

In your View file specify action attribute in form widget as shown in the below code

```
<?php 
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('yourcontrollername/actionname'),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            ));?>

<div class="row">

   <?php $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',array(
    'name'=>'files',
    'accept'=>'jpg|png',
    'max'=>3,
    'remove'=>Yii::t('ui','Remove'),
    //'denied'=>'', message that is displayed when a file type is not allowed
    //'duplicate'=>'', message that is displayed when a file appears twice
    'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>25),
)); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

In yourController actionUplaod as shown below

```
public function actionUpload(){
        echo "hi";
        var_dump($_FILES['files']);
    }
```